# GLPI - I can't connect to my database during GLPI setup. The server answered: Connection refused

Tags: docker, mariadb, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm new to coding and deploying infrastructures in the cloud. I want to deploy GLPI in an AKS cluster. It is in a different namespace than the database MariaDB. I created a DNS to connect to GLPI and configured the TLS with Let's Encrypt (I use the test server for practice).

My AKS cluster services and pods are running and valid (I checked with `kubectl describe pods [podName] -n [namespaceName]` and did the same for the services). The docker images are properly and successfully pulled into my pods.

When I connect to my GLPI with `glpi-v1.projetpro.space` I can start the setup and try to connect to my database. However i get the following error message : `Can't connect to the database The server answered: Connection refused`.

[Connection_Refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FafEG.png)

For the database setup I provide the database host : `db1-service.database1.svc.cluster.local`, the user : `glpi1-user` and the user's password (I provided the environment variables in my deployment with a configMap and Kubernetes secrets encoded in base64).

I used the FQDN for the database host as the deployments and services of my database and my GLPI are in different namespaces. If I want them to be able to connect I need to use the FQDN (according to the Kubernetes doc I found).

This is my code :

```
# glpi-v1.yaml

# Deployment of Redis
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: glpi-one
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-glpi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-glpi
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: redis-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: redis-pvc
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        args: ["--requirepass", "$(REDIS_PWD)"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-vol
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "no"
        - name: REDIS_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: redis-secret
              key: password
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis

---
# Service for Redis (Cluster IP)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
  namespace: glpi-one
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis-glpi

---
# ConfigMap for Environment Variables for Mariadb for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: dbone-config
  namespace: database1
data:
  MARIADB_DATABASE: glpidb1
  MARIADB_USER: glpi1_user
  MARIADB_ROOT_HOST: db1-service.database1.svc.cluster.local # % per default


---
# Secret for Sensitive Data for Mariadb for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dbone-secret
  namespace: database1
type: Opaque
data:
  MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
  MARIADB_PASSWORD: 

---
# Service for Maria database for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db1-service
  namespace: database1
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mariadb-one


---
# Deployment of MariaDB for GLPI v1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mariadb-one
  namespace: database1
spec:
  serviceName: db1-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mariadb
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: dbone-vol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dbone-pvc
      containers:
        - name: mariadb
          image: dunvael/db_v10.0.9 # Spécifier ici le nom de l'image mariadb utilisée. Format : compteDocker/nomRepertoire:tagImage dunvael/db_v10.0.9:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
          - name: dbone-vol
            mountPath: /data # /var/lib/mysql
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: dbone-config
            - secretRef:
                name: dbone-secret
      restartPolicy: Always

---
# PV Claim creation for Mariadb for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dbone-pvc
  namespace: database1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---
# ConfigMap for Environment Variables for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: glpi-one-config
  namespace: glpi-one
data:
  MARIADB_DATABASE: glpidb1
  MARIADB_USER: glpi1_user
  DB_HOST: db1-service.database1.svc.cluster.local # Points to MariaDB service, default = localhost
  DB_PORT: '3306'
  DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: FR


---
# Secret for Sensitive Data for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dbone-secret
  namespace: glpi-one
type: Opaque
data:
  MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
  MARIADB_PASSWORD: 

---
# Deployment of GLPI v1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: glpi-one
  namespace: glpi-one
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: glpi-one
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: glpi-one
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-chown-data
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/glpi /var/log/glpi /var/lib/glpi"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: glpi-data
          mountPath: /var/www/glpi
        - name: glpi-logs
          mountPath: /var/log/glpi
        - name: glpi-var
          mountPath: /var/lib/glpi
      containers:
        - name: glpi
          image: dunvael/glpi_v10.0.9 # Spécifier ici le nom de l'image GLPI utilisée
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: glpi-one-config
            - secretRef:
                name: dbone-secret
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
          volumeMounts:
          - name: glpi-data
            mountPath: /var/www/glpi
          - name: glpi-logs
            mountPath: /var/log/glpi
          - name: glpi-var
            mountPath: /var/lib/glpi
          env:
          - name: REDIS
            value: "redis-service"
          - name: REDIS_PWD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name:  redis-secret
                key: password
      volumes:
      - name: glpi-data
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: glpi-logs
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: glpi-var
        emptyDir: {}
      restartPolicy: Always

---
# Service for GLPI v1 (Cluster IP)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: glpi-service
  namespace : glpi-one
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80 # Port accessible inside cluster
    targetPort: 80 # Port to forward to inside the pod
  - name: https
    port: 443 # Expose the additional port
    targetPort: 443 # Set the target port for the additional port
  selector:
    app: glpi-one

---
# PV Claim creation for GLPI v1
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-pvc
  namespace: glpi-one
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---
# Autoscale for GLPI v1
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: scale-glpi-one
  namespace: glpi-one
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: glpi-one
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 70
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 200Mi
```

I've checked many publications and can't seem to find an answer. Could you please advise me ? I apologize in advance if this is due to my inexperience or misunderstanding. Thank you very much.

What I've tried :
I checked all my services and pods, described them (with kubectl commands).

I tried to grant rights to my user with commands in an initcontainer in my mariadb deployment however the initcontainer kept crashing and my pod could not start.

```
# Deployment of MariaDB for GLPI v1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mariadb-one
  namespace: database1
spec:
  serviceName: db1-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mariadb
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: dbone-vol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dbone-pvc
      initContainers:
      - name: init-database
        image: mariadb:latest # Use an image with MySQL/MariaDB client tools
        command: ["sh", "-c", "mysql -h db1-service -u root -p$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON glpidb1.* TO ''glpi1_user''@''%'';'"]
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: dbone-secret
              key: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD # Use the root password stored in your secret
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: dbone-config
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dbone-vol
          mountPath: /data
      containers:
        - name: mariadb
          image: dunvael/db_v10.0.9
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
          - name: dbone-vol
            mountPath: /data
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: dbone-config
            - secretRef:
                name: dbone-secret
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I tried with localhost instead of the FQDN but I get the error message that the database is not found.

I tried to connect directly from my pod to the database but it kept failing (`kubectl exc -it [podName] -n [namespaceName]`). I checked several videos on how to connect and can't seem to understand what I'm missing or misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `initContainers` container isn't needed as by default [`GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user`](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/148b0e5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L419) is done by the entrypoint.

A connection refused is mostly likely an attempt at connection before the container is ready. Using a [healthcheck.sh](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh/) as a [readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) `command` will allow your init container to connect when its ready.

Other things:

- [MARIADB_ROOT_HOST](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-docker-official-image-environment-variables/#mariadb_root_host-mysql_root_host) is where the connection comes from, not necessary the same as the container itself.
- `mysql` isn't necessary in the container, from 11.0+ the `mariadb` executable will serve its place (and this existed from 10.4+).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. 
I used the `initContainers` when I searched for a solution but removed it after. Right now my code does not have the `initContainers` nor the `GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user`.

As I use the official MariaDB Docker image I don't have as much control on the content of the image as a DockerFile I would have created. I will use the healthcheck and see what informations are provided.

Comment: As the maintainer of the MariaDB Docker image, suggestions on [Dockerfile improvements](https://github.com/mariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues) that can be compatible with everyone else and have a general use case are welcome.